# Evaluate $ \int_{l/k}^\infty \frac{dr}{(r^2 + a^2)^{n/2}(k^2 - l^2/r^2)^{1/2}} $

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you evaluate this integral:

$$ I =  \int_{l/k}^\infty \frac{dr}{(r^2 + a^2)^{n/2}(k^2 - l^2/r^2)^{1/2}} \, \, \, ? $$

I know the solution, but I don't know how to derive it:
$$ I = \frac{k^{n-2}}{2(a^2k^2 + l^2)^{(n-1)/2}} \frac{\Gamma(1/2) \Gamma(n/2 - 1/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By substituting $ r^2 + a^2 = \frac{a^2 + l^2/k^2}{\xi}$ with $dr = - \frac{a^2 + l^2/k^2}{2r\xi^2} d\xi $ the integral is brought to the form (after a few algebraic transformations):
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{k^{n-2}}{2(a^2k^2 + l^2)^{n/2 - 1/2}} \int_0^1 d\xi \, \, \xi^{n/2 - 3/2} \, \, (1-\xi)^{-1/2} \\
&= \frac{k^{n-2}}{2(a^2k^2 + l^2)^{n/2 - 1/2}} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\frac12) \Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})};
\end{align}
in the last step the Beta function was used.